# Experience Editor error: Unnamed Component JSS component missing React/Vue/Angular implementation

Tags: jss

Error: "Unnamed Component JSS component missing React/Vue/Angular implementation. See the developer console for more information."

This error is sometimes seen in Experience Editor after these actions:
1. After deploying page content to Sitecore in Code-First mode
2. After adding a rendering to a page in Sitecore-First mode

What is the issue?

[image: Image of error in Experience Editor]

Answer (score 1):

The JSS SDK uses naming conventions to match rendering in Sitecore to JSS JavaScript components. The most common causes of this error are that the rendering definition item for the component exists in Sitecore, but the JavaScript code for the component has not been deployed to the instance, or the name of the JavaScript component does not match the name of the Sitecore rendering.

To resolve the error: verify the name of the JavaScript component, and then make sure JavaScript files are deployed to the Sitecore instance using the command `jss deploy files`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in the JSS angular application. Make sure the component definition matches in the manifest and deploy the files.

1. Check the component definition

```
    manifest.addComponent({
    name: '**Article**'
```

2. JSS deploy files - use this command